# Add reusable field type to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to define a custom field type and reuse that definition for multiple fields. I'm trying to do something like a template, but I don't want it to be defined dynamically.

For example, I have something in the system called "keywords" - keywords always have a specific mapping -

```
'keywords' => [
        'type'                => 'object',
        'properties'          => [
            'id'   => [
                'type' => 'integer'
            ],
            'name' => [
                'type' => 'string',
                'position_offset_gap'=>100,
                'analyzer'=>'my_keyword',
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

I have these throughout the system - post, media, folder, etc. and I have two kinds that are very similar - lets say keywords and categories.  It's the same definition, I just keep them separate for business reasons.

Ideally, what I would like to do is define a "keyword" type and then for a field I would just define

```
'keywords' => [
        'type' => 'keyword'
 ]
```

or something similar.  Then also when I want to change that definition I can do it in one place for all the fields using it.

Is this possible in Elasticsearch?  I'd prefer not to use index template because I like having my mappings explicit.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/dynamic-templates.html) + a naming convention for keyword fields. In practice, for example:

**(1)** Define a dynamic template that maps any field with a name starting by `k_` to your custom mapping

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        "keywords": {
          "match": "k_*",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "keyword",
            ...
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**(2)** Add the `k_` prefix to the name of any field that should apply your custom mapping (e.g., `k_post`, `k_media`, ...)

Of course, you can choose any other naming convention for your keyword fields (e.g., `*_keywords` `k*`, ...)